# TSQL JSON_VALUE Array with no name

Tags: json, t-sql

Trying to get the following working in MS SQL 2016 but need a MS SQL JSON guru to help out.

I have a table with JSON in a text string

```
  [
  {
    "static-list-id": 37,
    "internal-list-id": 41,
    "timestamp": 1554831874747,
    "vid": 9350104,
    "is-member": true
  },
  {
    "static-list-id": 39,
    "internal-list-id": 43,
    "timestamp": 1554831874931,
    "vid": 9350104,
    "is-member": true
  }
  ]'
```

Here's my SQL statement, think I might need a JSON_QUERY

```
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE([MyNVarCharWithJSONColumn],'strict $."static-list-id"') AS static_list_id
FROM
  [MyTable] C
  WHERE ISJSON([MyNVarCharWithJSONColumn])>0
```

These are the results I'd like from the SQL statement, one row per

```sqll
static_list_id
--------------
37
39
```

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT a.static_list_id
FROM MyTable 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(MyNVarCharWithJSONColumn)
WITH (static_list_id INT N'$."static-list-id"') AS a;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93c6bf837bd3ed972a29a0e66210aba1)**

Comment: This is what I asked for thank you.  How can I add another column from the JSON into the list?

Comment: @Simon, you can place all the needed columns in the WITH-clause (comma separated).